# how to select the row having checkbox checked in a grid on button click?

Tags: jquery, html

I have a grid which contains a checkbox. I want to select the row of the `grid` for which the `checkbox` is checked. Screenshot attached.
 
 Need your help. I am new to Jquery and still learning.
[image]

Comment: select the row data which has checkbox checked.

Answer (score 1):

You could write it with [`closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) method like so!

We get the input that is checked with `input:checked` then we find the `tr` parent using the closest method.

```js
$('#check').on("click", function() {
  var checked = $('#asdf input:checked');
  console.log(checked.closest('tr'));
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="asdf">
  <tr>
    <th>Month</th>
    <th>Savings</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
    <td>$100</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
    <td>$1050</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
    <td>$1002</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<button id="check">check</button>
```

Comment: it will be decided on a button click(which is outside grid) not on checkbox click

Comment: @nikhiljain I've used a button to trigger the check

Comment: how to check if a row is selected or not ?

Comment: @nikhiljain in this example, we are getting the rows where the checkbox has been selected, what exactly is the issue with this code?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(":checkbox").change(function() {
        $(this).closest("tr").toggleClass("pinkrow", this.checked)
    })
});
```

```css
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td, th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}
.pinkrow{
background-color:pink;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<body>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>checkbox</th>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td><input type="checkbox" name="tr1" value="tr1" class="checkboxs"> </td>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td><input type="checkbox" name="tr2" value="tr2" class="checkboxs"> </td>
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td><input type="checkbox" name="tr3" value="tr3" class="checkboxs"> </td>
    <td>Ernst Handel</td>
    <td>Roland Mendel</td>
    <td>Austria</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td><input type="checkbox" name="tr4" value="tr4" class="checkboxs"> </td>
    <td>Island Trading</td>
    <td>Helen Bennett</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
 
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: but how to get the data of that row company,Contact,Country ?

Comment: and can we do on a button click which is present outside grid

Comment: @nikhiljain You seem to be using DataTable, shouldn't you have the data array to initialize this table with? Why do you need to "extract" the values from the table columns?

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if you are using a library for that datatable.

But with jQuery you could do something like this.

The jQuery code below should also work with your html structure.

```js
$(".dataTable > tbody").find("tr td:first-child input[type='checkbox']:checked").each(function (){ 
   $(this).parent().parent().addClass("selected")
});
```

```css
.selected >td{
background:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="dataTable">
<tr>
<td>
<input type="checkbox" checked="checked" />
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>
<input type="checkbox" />
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>
<input type="checkbox" checked="checked" />
</td>
</tr>

</table>
```